# What's the optimal stack to build offline-first React Native apps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm planning to play around with React Native soon. The goal is to be able to create simple **offline-first** apps with a low level of backend and frontend complexity.

1. What **stack** would you suggest to build such apps? We're talking
   routing, UI components, local database
2. Are there any specific **boilerplates** you'd recommend having a look
   at?

I am aware this is a primarily opinion-based subject, but I'm curious if any patterns emerge that could help me out deciding in which direction to go first.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try meteorJS, it will give you a very quick front- & backend in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [redux-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-offline) and [react-native-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-offline), for my opinion the last one in seems to be quite interesting.

I think it's not important which UI components library to use, [there is a good overview](https://www.instamobile.io/mobile-design/free-react-native-ui-kits/) of them, believe you will find something appropriate.

Regarding navigation, in my opinion, there are two really good libraries [react-navigation](http://react-navigation) and [react-native-navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation). I think you can successfully make your application using each of them, take a look at [this article,](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-choose-the-right-react-native-navigation-library-48679d63c9e9) probably it can help you to choose.

A few words about a database, in my projects I usually work with Reaml, it is an object-oriented database with good performance. But there are lots of options, take a look [at this article](http://object-oriented%20database).